# Smooth function with infinite oscillation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm curious to know if there's a function which:

1. Has an infinite number of solutions for $f(x)=0$ on $x \in [-a,a]$ for an $a > 0$ (like $f(x) = \sin(\frac 1 x)$)
2. Has an $n$th derivative for all $x\in[-a,a]$, for any $n$.
3. There is no interval $[b,c]\subset[-a,a]$ ($b<c$) for which $f(x)=0$ on the whole interval

Does such a function exist? If not, how could that be proven?

Comment: Has an $n$th what?

Comment: Well $f(x)\equiv 0$ fits the bill so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function

$$f(x) \; = \; \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

with $f(0) = 0$ has the property you want. I believe Ulisse Dini, on p. 229 of his 1878 book [**Fondamenti per la Teorica delle Funzioni di Variabili Reali**](https://books.google.com/books?id=jgQAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA229), was the first to publish such a function.