# find monotonic interval for real $C^\infty$ function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $f \in C^\infty \big( [0 , 1 ] \big)$ with $f(0)=0$ and a $0$-neighbourhood $[0,\varepsilon)$, such that $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,\varepsilon)$. 
Is it true, that there is a $\delta >0$, such that $f_{\vert [0,\delta)}$ is monotoniously increasing? If yes, how can we proof this?

Comment: I think you mean $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: Marginally related: [Smooth function with infinite oscillation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205980/13130)

Comment: Possibly $f(x) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left[2 - \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]$ with $f(0) = 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function:

$$f(x) = \exp(-\frac{1}{x})(\sin(\frac{1}{x}))^{2} + (\exp(-\frac{1}{x}))^{2}$$

is a possible counterexample.

(I was thinking about functions of type $x^{n} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which have finitely many good derivatives first and went from there)

---

Thanks @Héhéhé for spotting multiple shortcomings in this answer

Comment: This function does not seem to be smooth.

Comment: Sry, fixed my mistake

Comment: Your new function seems to vanishes for all $x=1/(n \pi)$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @Héhéhé vaild point. Need to add something super small monotonic and that'll be all then. I'll make yet another edit.

Comment: great counterexample, thanks you two. It works, because according to Wolfram Alpha  the derivative is $$\frac{e^{-2/x} \big(e^{1/x} \sin^2(1/x) - 2 e^{1/x} \sin(1/x) \cos(1/x) + 2\big)}{x^2}$$ and this function has infinitely many zeroes with changes of the sign in every neighbourhood of zero.