# If the zeros of a holomorphic function $f$ have an accumulation point, then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, constants

I'm having trouble with the proof of the next statement:

Let $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected. If $f$ is defined in $U$ and is holomorphic, and the set of its zeros have and accumulation point, then $f$ is constant on $U$.

I know how to prove this when that accumulation point is in $U$, but I don't know what to do in the other case. Hope you can help me, please.

Thank you.

Comment: The accumulation point *has to* be in $U$, otherwise the statement is not true.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: Indeed, if the OP's statement were true, then [the topic of a huge amount of research in complex analysis](https://www.google.com/search?q=boundary+complex+disk+%22cluster+set%22) would reduce to trivialities.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, and probably, all the maths would collapse.

Comment: It seems to me that this is often glossed over in the statement of the theorem.  For example, the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) on the identity theorem misstates the theorem, so far as I can see.

Comment: @saulspatz: *It seems to me that this is often glossed over in the statement of the theorem.* --- In fact, less than 2 weeks ago I nearly did this myself (in the statement), and actually did so in the application I was making, in the comments to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4203493/13130) (which I obviously recalled as I was writing my previous comment here).

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, the statement in the preamble to the linked Wikipedia article is sloppy, but if you read the actual statement of the lemma down below, they clarify that the accumulation point lies in the domain.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I realize that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not true.  For example, $\sin(1/z)$ with $U = \mathbb C \backslash \{0\}$.