# Can a non-zero smooth $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ have infinitely many zeroes?

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Given a non-negative, smooth function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. If there exists a sequence (of pairwise disjoint points) $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n  \in \mathbb{N}$, does it mean that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$?

Motivation: Consider smooth curves in polar coordinates that is a map $c: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 , t \mapsto r(t) \cdot (\cos(t),\sin(t))$. If we restrict this curve to a compact intervall, is it regular (i.e. $r'(t)^2 +r^2(t) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,2\pi)$) up to finitely many points or finitely many closed intervalls? This would follow, if the above conclusion holds.

Thoughts: By compactness we can find (by abuse of notation) a subsequence $x_n \rightarrow x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$. From the taylor expansion we see that all derivatives in $x$ must vanish, that is $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Remarks: Smooth function on a closed intervall means there is an extension to an open intervall containing it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function

Comment: Does "smooth" mean $C^1$ or $C^{\infty}$ or [something else](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-12/issue-1/Smooth-functions/10.1215/S0012-7094-45-01206-3.short)? The term "smooth" is used differently by different authors.

Comment: Related: [Smooth function with infinite oscillation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2205980/13130)

Comment: Even more: Every closed proper subset of $[a,b]$ can be realized as the zero-level set of such a function. See answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98577/infinitely-differentiable-function-with-given-zero-set).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start with $f_1(x) = \sin(1/x)$, which has infinitely many zeroes, but it's clearly not smooth (not even continuous). You can square it to get a nonnegative function $f_2(x) = \sin^2(1/x)$.

As you observed, if $f$ is to be smooth, a [flat function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) has to appear, e.g. $e^{-1/x^2}$. So consider
$$f_3(x) = e^{-1/x^2} \sin^2(1/x).$$
You should be able to check that the zero of $e^{-1/x^2}$ at $x=0$ is so strong that the product is smooth, and in fact $f_3^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for each natural $n$.