# Continuously differentiable functions and oscillations near a point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, real-numbers

I was just reading a bit about continuosly differentiable functions and I found that one 'standard' example of a function that differentiable but not continuously differentiable is $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Now I  have the following conjecture:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^+_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuously differentiable function. Asume that there exists $s=\inf\{ t>0: f(t)<0 \}.$ Is it true that it is always possible to find an interval $J=(s,s+\delta)$ such that for every $t\in J$,$f(t)<0$?

I cannot find a counterexample (a function that oscillates near $s$) for this, but I am stuck showing its validity. Can you please give some help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe something like $f(x) =x^{10} sin (1/x)$ for $x > 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$. Then $f$ is continuously differentiable, $s=0$ as you have defined it, but $f$ is both positive and negative infinitely often in any neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: I don't understand that purpose of the requirement "Assume there exists $s=\inf\{ t>0: f(t)<0 \}.$" Since **every** nonempty set has an infimum, this requirement is simply "there exists $t>0$ such that $f(t)<0$". Maybe you mean "assume there exists $t>0$ such that $f(t)<0,$ and let $s=\inf\{ t>0: f(t)<0 \}$", although this doesn't work and you probably want to use $s = \inf\{ t\geq 0: f(t)<0 \}.$ That said, possibly the example I give in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2206029/13130) (due to Dini, from 1878) will be of interest.

Comment: *although this doesn't work* --- Oops, defining $s$ by $s=\inf\{ t>0: f(t)<0 \}$ is OK, although $s=0$ is possible. However, I don't see any reason why we would want to require $s>0.$

Comment: Just by the way!  The example you called "standard" is part of a family that everyone should know well.  It can be used for a multitude of counterexamples.  Read this article if you can find it:  *Kaptanoğlu, H. Turgay, In praise of $y=x^αsin(1/x)$. Amer. Math. Monthly 108 (2001), no. 2, 144–150.*